# $2^{x-3} + \frac {15}{2^{3-x}} = 256$

Tags: exponential-function

$$2^{x-3} + \frac {15}{2^{3-x}} = 256$$

- Find the unknown $x$.

My attempt:

We know that $x^y . x^b = x^{y+b}$.

$$2^x . 2^{-3} + 15. 2^{-3+x} = 2^8$$

and

$$2^x . 2^{-3} + 15. 2^{-3} . 2^x = 2^8$$

From here, we get

$$2^x + 15 = 2^8$$

However, I'm stuck at here and waiting for your kindest helps.

Thank you.

Comment: @FlybyNight That was my mistake.

Comment: Your "from here we get $2^x+ 15= 2^8$" is wrong.  You have $(2^x)(2^{-3})+ (15)(2^{-3})(2^x)= 2^8$, factoring out $(2^{-3})(2^x)$ gives $(2^{-3})(2^x)(1+ 15)= 2^{-3}(2^x)(16)= 2^8$.  Since $16= 2^4$, that is $2(2^x)= 2^8$ so $2^x= 2^8/2= 2^7$.

Answer (score 4):

writing $$\frac{2^x}{8}+\frac{15}{8}2^x=2^8$$ so
$$2^x\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{15}{8}\right)=2^8$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If we put $$t=2^{x-3}, $$

the equation becomes

$$t+15t=256$$

or
$$t=16$$

$$2^{x-3} = 16$$

$$x=7$$

Comment: Can we solve the questions which like this with your method? It made it easier I think.

Comment: It looks like you read the question wrong, or it was typed wrong.

Comment: @FlybyNight It was typed correctly.

Comment: According to how the question is written, we actually get $t+\frac {15}{\frac 1t}=256$...

Comment: What if we solve this question by putting $t$?

Comment: It must be $x = 7$

Comment: Post-correction is a little more than a "**hint**" ;-)

Comment: @FlybyNight What do you think about this method?

Comment: and can we apply this method for all?

Comment: @Enzo Now that it has been corrected, it's fine. It won't work in general. But a lot of Maths is like that: some things work some of the time, other things work the rest of the time. :-/

Comment: @FlybyNight Do they have to be same? I mean like if it been $2^{x-3} + \frac {15}{2^{6-x}} = 256$ Could we apply this method?

Comment: @Enzo For this, use the fact that $\frac{1}{2^{6-x}} = 2^{x-6} = 2^{-3}\cdot 2^{x-3}$. That gives $2^{x-3} + 15 \cdot 2^{-3} \cdot 2^{x-3} = 256$. Putting $t = 2^{x-3}$ gives $t + \frac{15}{8} t = 256$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As $2^{-y}=\dfrac1{2^y}$

$$\dfrac1{2^{3-x}}=2^{-(3-x)}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{x-3} + 15\cdot 2^{x-3} = 256;$

$2^{x-3}(1+15) =256;$

$2^{x-3} =256/(16)= 16;$

$x-3=4$ , by inspection.

$x=7.$

Note:

$\dfrac{1}{2^{3-x}}= 2^{x-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

"$2^x . 2^{-3} + 15. 2^{-3} . 2^x = 2^8"$

"From here, we get"

"$2^x + 15 = 2^8$"

Uh....What?    No, you don't.

You get

$2^x . 2^{-3}*2^3 + 15. 2^{-3}2^3 . 2^x = 2^8*2^3"$

$2^x + 15*2^x = 2^{8+3}$

So $16 *2^x = 2^{11}$

$2^{x+4} = 2^{11}$

$x+4 = 11$

$x = 7$.

====

I'd find it easier to do. Let $y = x-3$ so

$2^y + \frac 15{2^{-y}} = 256$

$2^y + 15*2^y = 256$

$2^y(1 + 15) = 256$

$2^y(16)= 256$

$2^y = \frac {256}{16} = \frac {2^8}{2^4} = 2^4$

$y = x-3 = 4$

$x = 3$.

=====

Someone else suggested: Let $t = 2^{x-3}$ so

$t + \frac {15}{\frac 1t} = 256$ so

$t + 15t = 256$ etc....